# newgeometry + restoregeometry creates empty pages before and after the page of interest

Tags: geometry, blank-page, remove

I have a long table on one page, for which I tried to use newgeometry before \begin{table} and restoregeometry after \end{table}. This creates an empty page before the page of interest, and another empty page after that page of interest. Is there a way to get rid of these empty pages?

Thank you!

Comment: You're much more likely to get meaningful help if you post a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that). How I would approach this depends a lot of what kinds of changes you're making to the geometry, and whether a float is really necessary or not.

Comment: don't use geometry, just put `\vspace{-5cm}` before`\end{table}`

Comment: Note that changing the page geometry issues a `\clearpage` before and after.